# Joomla newsflash items linking to separate page

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5

Joomla 2.5
Let's say I got "News" category with some articles inside and modules, let's call them "module1", "module2" and up to 10. 
Normally, if I got menu item called "News" with category view under it (it's called blog or something in Joomla) and I set only "module1" to be displayed there, all the items from this category will be displayed with the same layout.
However, if I add ie. "module2", which is a newsflash, to my homepage, items from "News" category will be displayed with homepage layout, with all the modules shown. I'd like them to be displayed as if they were on "News" page. How to do that?

Answer: add articles to "hidden" menu is not acceptable. Imagine blog, where you have to add all your posts to any kind of menu.

Visual explanation:
Normally, a menu position which lists articles form category and has only two modules (call them module1 and module2) enabled, will look like this: http://imm.io/FGrJ
If you click any item, you will be redirected to a page with the same layout (notice: I don't have to add all articles to menu, just article listing page): http://imm.io/FGrP

However, if I add newsflash module on my homepage, which is full of modules, clicking an item will display article on homepage, in area that I called main content. Which is bad. I'd like it to open just like article from articles listing. Here is screen: http://imm.io/FGsR

Comment: I don't get what you are asking for.. maybe you could explain with some images?

Comment: I did not answer it, just gave an example of answer that doesn't satisfy me. I'll try to add some images later.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_control_module_display_when_linking_to_an_article_with_no_menu_item) article on the Joomla docs gives a good idea of what your tying to do as I understand it. As you don't wish to have menu items as you state in the question I think the best way is what they label as number 3 at the bottom - installing an extension that provides detailed control over where a module displays. Their featured module is [Advanced Module Manager](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/modules-management/10307) - which comes from NoNumber - something a lot of sites use and has a proven track record. However there is an entire section of modules on Joomla Extension Directory [here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/modules-management)

Comment: Wow, thanks for this module! It's great and might work as a workaround, however it doesn't solve the problem completely. The article is still displayed on homepage, which means it's layout isn't customized like that from blog view (shows fields like "created", "author" etc). And, what's important from SEO view, the url is different. Menu item will have url like /news/133-news/28-something-new-happened, this item will have /133-news/28-something-new-happened (notice menu alias in first url).

Comment: @alekwisnia Hmmm going to have to pass I'm afraid. If you're really going to go for it - then I'd suggest a SEO control module for the links. As for the parameters going into the articles. Perhaps control them through passing through the variables in the link. I guess JRouter combined with a component would still convert them?